# What is the value of set::end++?

Tags: c++, stl

First of all, I use `set::lower_bound` to find something, then I need to check some neighbors of that value in both directions. My code ends up in infinite loop and I think it can be due to odd behavior after this:

```
idx = set.lower_bound(val);
++idx;
while(idx != set.end() && /*...*/)
{
  /*...*/
  idx++;
}
```

Let's assume that lower_bound returned `set::end`. I suppose after incrementing `set::end` something weird takes place and while loop goes into long journey to the stars :) But I'm not sure and curious about it.

Comment: `set::end()` already "points" one past the end of any valid element.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is undefined behaviour to increment an end-iterator. Don't do it.